# Convergence in $\mathcal{D}^\prime(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: distribution-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem about distributions:

"Let $f\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ a test function with $\mathrm{supp}(f)\subseteq(-1,1)$ and $\||f|\|_1=1$. For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $f_k$ to be defined by $f_k(x)=\int_{1/k}^kf(k(x-t))\,\mathrm{d}t$. Denote by $\Lambda_k$ the usual functional on $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ given by $$\langle \Lambda_k,\varphi\rangle=\int_\mathbb{R} \varphi(x)f_k(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Show that $\Lambda_k\in\mathcal{D}^\prime(\mathbb{R})$ and $\Lambda_k\stackrel{\mathcal{D}^\prime(\mathbb{R})}{\longrightarrow}H$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function."

My attempt: The expression $\int_\mathbb{R}\int_{1/k}^k\varphi(x)f(k(x-t))\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x$ remember us the use of approximate identities, so I think that we could use the ideas behind that approach. However, we found the with the problem that appears $"-t"$ and it should be $-x$; moreover $f$ is not non negative in general and also the inf and sup limits of the inner integral cause me a conflict.

Do you have some idea?

Comment: This can't be true, if you take $f$ negative, you're getting the wrong signs.

Comment: I thought it, so i tryied to find a counterexample ($f=-\chi_{(-1,1)}$, but the expression for $\Lambda_k $ becomes "hard". On the other hand, what if we suppose in adition that $f\ge0$?

Comment: The statement of the problem seems full of mistakes. Perhaps the condition $\int f=1$ is meant instead of $||f||_1=1$. Also, the formula defining $f_k(x)$ looks very suspicious.

Comment: I suppose there is a typo error. I'll change that condition.

Comment: You meant $f_k(x)=\int_{1/k}^kk\, f(k(x-t))\,\mathrm{d}t$ with $C = \int f$ then $ f_k = k f(k.) \ast 1_{[1/k,k]}  \to C \delta \ast 1_{[0,\infty)}= C 1_{[0,\infty)}$

Comment: @reuns: That was my guess too.